# Android activity management: Is there a good reason not to return on isFinishing() in all the starter lifecycle methods?

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin

I'm using Android on Xamarin, if this is relevant. Consider the following situation:

1. Activity A's OnCreate() executes and an error is encountered
2. Activity A spawns Activity B (an error message dialog) and OnCreate() returns
3. Activity B is dismissed
4. Activity A's OnActivityResult executes, where finish() is called

In this situation on Xamarin, sometimes OnCreate/OnResume of Activity A will have time to execute before Activity A is finished. For instance, this can happen if a configuration change occurred when Activity B was in the foreground. This can result in the error message dialog being displayed more than once, which is not desired.

This is easily alleviated by querying isFinishing() before displaying the error message in Activity A. But I'm thinking that this behavior can cause more subtle bugs, e.g. if OnCreate/OnResume have side effects that change global state in the app.

Is there a good reason not to do

```
if (isFinishing()) { return; }
```

at the start of every activity's OnCreate, OnRestart and OnResume?